# Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, ccs

Quiere aplicar un jquery o realizar una función para trabajar con el dom desde mi archivo .tsx en este caso es un navbar.tsx, pero me da error, estoy realizando un ejemplo básico que vi en internet de un navbar transparente y al bajar el scroll este utilice la propiedad background-color para que pase mediante una transición de transparente a negro:

Antes de mostrar el codigo, quiero comentarles que mi codigo esta en bajo el Formato TS en el framework Next.

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-danger-with-children */
import Image from 'next/image';

const Navbar = (props ) => {
  return (
        <>
    <nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-md-3 scrolling-navbar">
      <div className="container">
            <Image src="/imagenes/logo.png" className="logo" width="320" height="90" />
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <div className="mx-auto"></div>
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

        <script
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: 
                nav = document.querySelector('nav');
                window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
                    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
                        nav.classList.add('bg-dark', 'shadow');
                    } else {
                        nav.classList.remove('bg-dark', 'shadow');
                    }
                        })
                        ,
            }}
            >   </script>
    </>
        )
}

export default Navbar;
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

Server Error
Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el espacio entre ya que está detectando que tienes dos cosas el children (espacio en blanco) y el innerHtml:

```
<script ...></script>
```

Creo que está detectando que tienes dos componentes a la vez.

De todas formas yo añadiría dos cosas extras, intenta evitar dangerouslySetInnerHTML ya que no es una buena práctica y ya que estás trabajando con React lo suyo sería que trabajases con los estados de react para cambiar las clases dependiendo del scroll en vez de usar un script dentro del html.
Y segundo, dado que utilizar Next.js con server side rendering, comprueba que en el lado del servidor no da problemas el renderizado dado que el objeto windows no está definido, se puede comprobar con un:

```
if ( typeof window !== "undefined" ){...
```